# Mathematica returns incorrect evaluation of integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Consider the integral
$$
\begin{equation}
    u(x):= \lim_{\eta \to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d s}{s^2 + 1} \left( 
    \frac{1}{x - i \eta - \sqrt{s^2 + 1}} 
    - 
    \frac{1}{x - i \eta + \sqrt{s^2 + 1}} \right)
    .
\end{equation}
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Mathematica will evaluate this integral without complaint

```
In[] : = Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && \[Eta] > 0, Limit[Integrate[1/(s^2 + 1) (1/(x - I \[Eta] - Sqrt[s^2 + 1]) - 1/(x - I \[Eta] + Sqrt[s^2 + 1])), {s, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], \[Eta] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]
```

and returns
$$
u_\mathrm{MMA}(x) = -\frac{4 \arccos\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}{\left| x\right| \sqrt{1-x^2} }
$$
However this answer cannot be correct, it is an even function ($u(-x) = u(x)$), whereas the definition manifestly has the propery $u(-x) = u(x)^*$  (this can be confirmed using `NIntegrate` for small finite values of $\eta$). I.e. both the real and imaginary parts of $u_\mathrm{MMA}(x)$ are even, when the imaginary part should be odd.

Is there a way of getting Mathematica to return the correct answer for these types of integral?

Comment: In 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro I obtain$$\fbox{$-\frac{4 \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}\text{ if }-1<x<1$}$$

Comment: @user64494 That's interesting. I am running version 12.0.0 on Mac OS X x86 (64bit).

Comment: And $$ \frac{4 \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-(x-i \eta )^2}\right)}{\sqrt{(x-i \eta )^2-(x-i \eta )^4}}$$ for the integral under consideration.

Comment: @user64494 nonetheless your result is still even in $x$? And therefore still incorrect?

Comment: Note that the 12.2 answer, given the assumption that $|x| < 1$, is real;  and therefore $u(-x) = u^*(x) \Leftrightarrow u(-x) = u(x)$ under these assumptions.

Comment: @ComptonScattering:  $$ \frac{4 \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-(x-i \eta )^2}\right)}{\sqrt{(x-i \eta )^2-(x-i \eta )^4}}$$ is not an even function of $x$: e.g. think of the expression under the square root in the denominator.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, so you are saying MMA evaluates the Limit incorrectly. Either way the bottom line (after taking $\eta \to 0$) is incorrect. Ideally I would like to know how to get the correct answer to drop out without having to do the math myself.

Comment: @ComptonScattering: Thi limit of $$ \frac{4 \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-(x-i \eta )^2}\right)}{\sqrt{(x-i \eta )^2-(x-i \eta )^4}}$$ as $\eta \to 0$ is an even function of $x$ on the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, but I have not assumed $x \in (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that Mathematica is handling the assumptions concerning `x` incorrectly.  If you explicitly tell it that $x < -1$, $|x| \leq 1$, or $x > 1$, it produces three slightly different functional forms:

```
ulow[x_] = Assuming[x < -1 && \[Eta] > 0, ... ]
umid[x_] = Assuming[1 > x > -1 && \[Eta] > 0, ... ]
uhigh[x_] = Assuming[1 < x && \[Eta] > 0, ... ]

(* (4 I (\[Pi] + ArcSin[x]))/(x Sqrt[-1 + x^2]) *)
(* -((4 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - x^2]])/Sqrt[x^2 - x^4]) *)
(* (4 I ArcSin[x])/(x Sqrt[-1 + x^2]) *)
```

So if desired, we can assemble these into a `Piecewise` function that works for all `x`:

```
u[x_] := Piecewise[{{ulow[x], x< -1}, {umid[x], -1 <= x <= 1}, {uhigh[x], x > 1}}] 
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[u[x]]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

This does appear to have the property that $\Re(u(x))$ is even in $x$ and $\Im(u(x))$ is odd in $x$.

Comment: Great, thank you. This is a useful workaround. It is a shame that it requires identifying the discontinuities by hand.